# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space during bytea download

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using this code to download bytea object from PostgreSQL:

```
public void initFileDBData() throws SQLException, IOException
{
    if (ds == null)
    {
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
    }
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

    if (conn == null)
    {
        throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PROCEDURE_FILES WHERE ID = ?");

        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String file_name = rs.getString("FILE_NAME");
            InputStream binaryStreasm = rs.getBinaryStream("FILE");
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

            ec.responseReset();
            ec.setResponseContentLength(binaryStreasm.available());
            ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file_name + "\"");

            byte[] buf;

                buf = new byte[binaryStreasm.available()];
                int offset = 0;
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((offset < buf.length) && ((numRead = binaryStreasm.read(buf, offset, buf.length - offset)) >= 0))
                {
                    offset += numRead;
                }

            HttpServletResponse response
                = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();

            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file_name);
            response.getOutputStream().write(buf);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (ps != null)
        {
            ps.close();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

But when I start to download the code I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on this line:

```
 buf = new byte[binaryStreasm.available()];
```

Can I somehow optimize the code to consume less memory?

Updated code:

```
public void initFileDBData() throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *, octet_length(FILE) as file_length FROM PROCEDURE_FILES WHERE ID = ?");

            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String file_name = rs.getString("FILE_NAME");
                FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

                ec.responseReset();
                ec.setResponseContentLength(rs.getInt("file_length"));
                ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file_name + "\"");

                HttpServletResponse response
                    = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext().getResponse();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                try (InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FILE");
                    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream())
                {
                    int numRead = 0;

                    while ((numRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                }

                response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file_name);
                response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ps != null)
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `available()` is not the actual size of the stream. It's just an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read without blocking - it can be smaller than the size of the stream, and it can even be larger. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) specifically says *It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream*.

Comment: Ok, how I can fix this?

Comment: Also I see the ResultSet object rs is not closed. That could be a memory leak too.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code.

Comment: Your result set still won't be closed if an exception is thrown.  Assuming you're using Java 7 or newer, you should use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block to ensure that the `ResultSet` is closed at the end.  In older versions, use try/finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reliance on `InputStream::available` here is wrong. Its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) says:

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.
>
> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. **It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.**

(Emphasis mine)

So you face two problems:

1. What number to pass in the `Content-Length` header if you don't have an exact size for the output stream?
2. How to pass the stream from the result set to the response without keeping all of the data in memory at the same time.

I would solve the first problem by changing the query a little, so that it returns the actual size of the `bytea` field.

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *,octet_length(FILE) as file_length FROM PROCEDURE_FILES WHERE ID = ?");
```

The PostgreSQL function `octet_length` gives you the length of a `bytea` column in bytes.

Once you have that, you can use

```
ec.setResponseContentLength(rs.getInt("file_length"));
```

Now, for the second problem, you should avoid reading everything into a large buffer. If you use the number from `rs.getInt("file_length')` to allocate the buffer, you'll run into the same memory problem. You should just copy the stream gradually.

If you have Apache Commons IO, You can use `IOUtils.copy()` to copy the stream from the result set to the output stream of the response. Avoid getting the binary stream until after you have set up the response content type and length, and then do:

```
IOUtils.copy( rs.getBinaryStream("FILE"), response.getOutputStream() );
```

If you don't want to use Apache Commons IO, you can write your own loop - using a *small* buffer. Again, first set up the response content type and length, and then do something like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

try ( InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FILE");
      OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream() ) {

    int numRead = 0;

    while ( ( numRead = input.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, numRead );
    }

}
```

And then complete the response, close the result set, and you're done. I used the try-with-resources syntax which automatically closes the streams when it's done.

By the way, there is no reason to use `while` to read a single row, and your code will not work if the query returns more than one row. You can use a simple `if (rs.next())` and throw some exception or present some error to the user in the `else`.

Comment: I updated the post. Now I get `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1088381651` when I try to download file with size 518 Mb

Comment: Ok, post is updated. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Does it happen with all files in the database or just with big ones?

Comment: I can successfully download PDF files around 2-3 megabytes. This problem appears with files big around 500 megabytes.

Comment: @PeterPenzov This seems to be a problem in memory allocation on the PostgreSQL server side. You should perhaps try not to use `bytea` but instead use BLOBS.

Comment: I tried also this: http://postgresql.nabble.com/org-postgresql-util-PSQLException-ERROR-column-quot-file-quot-is-of-type-oid-but-expression-is-of-tya-td5902345.html Can you leave here some comment please why I get 0 bytes as a result. I will open a new post if it's needed.

Comment: @PeterPenzov One question at a time. You're saying that the download succeeds for 2-3 mega. That means this procedure works. If you have other problems, you should open a new question - perhaps after you try using BLOBs to solve the size limit issue.

Comment: Ok, By BLOBS you mean OID?

Comment: Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092628/empty-file-after-downlaod

Comment: I mean [Large Objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/largeobjects.html), which indeed are represented in the table itself as OIDs and are a little more complicated to handle - but they are not loaded into memory in a single read and therefore will not cause the problem you have with very large files.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `binaryStreasm.available()` returns a big value such that it tries to create a byte array that cannot fit into memory, try to set small value like `512` or `1024`.

The other problem here is that you try to load the entire content of the `bytea` object into memory which is not the right way to do it especially if you have to deal with big binary content like here. You are supposed to write the content into `response.getOutputStream()` or write it first into a temporary file and then write the content of the file into `response.getOutputStream()`

Comment: Now I get `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1088381651`

Comment: where does it come from? what is the stack trace?

Comment: This comes when I start file download.

Comment: Can you show me code sample how to write the binary object into `response.getOutputStream()`, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you have it already in the answer of RealSkeptic